# AWK: statistics operations of multi-column CSV data

Tags: csv, awk

With the aim to perform some statistical analysis of multi-column data I am analyzing big number of CSV filles using the following bash + AWK routine:

```
#!/bin/bash
home="$PWD"
# folder with the outputs
rescore="${home}"/rescore 
# folder with the folders to analyse
storage="${home}"/results
#cd "${home}"/results
cd ${storage}
csv_pattern='*_filt.csv'


while read -r d; do
awk -v rescore="$rescore" '
FNR==1 {
   if (n)
      mean[suffix] = s/n
   prefix=suffix=FILENAME
   sub(/_.*/, "", prefix)
   sub(/\/[^\/]+$/, "", suffix)
   sub(/^.*_/, "", suffix)
   s=n=0
}
FNR > 1 {
   s += $3
   ++n
}
END {
   out = rescore "/" prefix ".csv"
   mean[suffix] = s/n
   print prefix ":", "dG(mean)" > out
   for (i in mean)
      printf "%s: %.2f\n", i, mean[i] >> out
   close(out)
}' "${d}_"*/${csv_pattern} #> "${rescore}/"${d%%_*}".csv"
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '*_*_*' | awk -F '[_/]' '!seen[$2]++ {print $2}')
```

Basically the script takes ensemble of CSV files belonged to the same prefix (defined as the naming pattern occured at the begining of the directory contained CSV, for example 10V1 from 10V1_cne_lig1) and calculate for it the mean value for the numbers in the third column:

```
# input *_filt.csv located in the folder 10V1_cne_lig1001
ID, POP, dG
1, 142, -5.6500
2, 10, -5.5000
3, 2, -4.9500
```

add 1 string to 10V1.csv, which is organized in 2 column format i) the name of the suffix of the folder with initial CSV; ii) the mean value calculated for all numbers in the third column (dG) of input.csv:

```
# this is two column format of output.csv: 10V1.csv
10V1: dG(mean)
lig1001: -5.37
```

in this way for 100 CSV filles such output.csv should contain 100 lines with the mean values, etc

I need to introduce a small modification to my AWK part of my routine that would add the 3rd column to the output CSV with RMSD value (as the measure of the differences between initial dG values) of the initial data (dG), which had been used to calculate the MEAN value. Using AWK syntax, with a particular MEAN value the RMS could be expressed as

```
mean=$(awk -F , '{sum+=$3}END{printf "%.2f", sum/NR}' $csv)
rmsd=$(awk -v mean=$mean '{++n;sum+=($NF-mean)^2} END{if(n) printf "%.2f", sqrt(sum/n)}' $csv)
```

Here is expected output for 5 means and 5 rmsds values calculated for 5 CSV logs (the first one is corresponded to my above example!):

```
10V1: dG(mean): RMSD (error)
lig1001 -5.37 0.30
lig1002 -8.53 0.34
lig1003 -6.57 0.25
lig1004 -9.53 0.00 # rmsd=0 since initial csv has only 1 line: no data variance 
lig1005 -8.11 0.39
```

How this addition could be incorporated into my main bash-AWK code with the aim to add the third RMSD column (for each of the processed CSV, thus taking each of the calculated MEAN) to the output.csv?

Comment: Can you please show 5 mean values and their corresponding `rmsd` values in expected output

Comment: here it is with some further explanations

Comment: ok but why does `mean=-9.53` have `rmsd=0` ?

Comment: becasue in that case the initial CSV (from which mean had been calculated)  contained only one line so there is no varriance in that case and RMSD=0 :-)

Comment: there is a valuable answer that I am going to accept! Please consult it since it contain good solution for RMSD calculation. BTW we found small bug related mostly to AWK part: in the case of one of the set of CSV it put the header contained suffix into the second line like this lig1: -7.04 0.20 10V2: dG(mean) dG(rmsd) # it should be always on the first line of output.csv!! lig2: -5.79 0.45 
Actually I have no idea why: I just added a small suffix "data_" to prefix and it fixed this problem: print "data_" prefix, "dG(rescored)", "dG(rmsd)" > out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate both of `mean` and `rmsd` within the `awk` code.
Would you please try the following `awk` code:

```
awk -v rescore="$rescore" '
FNR==1 {
   if (n) {                     # calculate the results of previous file
      m = s / n                 # mean
      var = s2 / n - m * m      # variance
      if (var < 0) var = 0      # avoid an exception due to round-off error
      mean[suffix] = m          # store the mean in an array
      rmsd[suffix] = sqrt(var)
   }
   prefix=suffix=FILENAME
   sub(/_.*/, "", prefix)
   sub(/\/[^\/]+$/, "", suffix)
   sub(/^.*_/, "", suffix)
   s = 0                        # sum of $3
   s2 = 0                       # sum of $3 ** 2
   n = 0                        # count of samples
}
FNR > 1 {
   s += $3
   s2 += $3 * $3
   ++n
}
END {
   out = rescore "/" prefix ".csv"
   m = s / n
   var = s2 / n - m * m
   if (var < 0) var = 0
   mean[suffix] = m
   rmsd[suffix] = sqrt(var)

   print prefix ":", "dG(mean)", "dG(rmsd)" > out
   for (i in mean)
      printf "%s: %.2f %.2f\n", i, mean[i], rmsd[i] >> out
   close(out)
}'
```

Here is the version to print the lowest value of `dG`.

```
awk -v rescore="$rescore" '
FNR==1 {
   if (n) {                     # calculate the results of previous file
      m = s / n                 # mean
      var = s2 / n - m * m      # variance
      if (var < 0) var = 0      # avoid an exception due to round-off error
      mean[suffix] = m          # store the mean in an array
      rmsd[suffix] = sqrt(var)
      lowest[suffix] = min
   }
   prefix=suffix=FILENAME
   sub(/_.*/, "", prefix)
   sub(/\/[^\/]+$/, "", suffix)
   sub(/^.*_/, "", suffix)
   s = 0                        # sum of $3
   s2 = 0                       # sum of $3 ** 2
   n = 0                        # count of samples
   min = 0                      # lowest value of $3
}
FNR > 1 {
   s += $3
   s2 += $3 * $3
   ++n
   if ($3 < min) min = $3       # update the lowest value
}
END {
   if (n) {                     # just to avoid division by zero
      m = s / n
      var = s2 / n - m * m
      if (var < 0) var = 0
      mean[suffix] = m
      rmsd[suffix] = sqrt(var)
      lowest[suffix] = min
   }
   out = rescore "/" prefix ".csv"
   print prefix ":", "dG(mean)", "dG(rmsd)", "dG(lowest)" > out
   for (i in mean)
      printf "%s: %.2f %.2f %.2f\n", i, mean[i], rmsd[i], lowest[i] > out
}' file_*.csv
```

- I've assumed all `dG` values are negative. If there is any chance the
  value is greater than zero, modify the line `min = 0` which initializes
  the variable to considerably big value (10,000 or whatever).
- Please apply your modifications regarding the filenames, if needed.
- The suggestions by Ed Morton are also included although the results will be the same.

Comment: thank you so much! it works well but there is a bug somewhere: in the case of one of the set of CSV it put the header contained suffix into the second line like this lig1: -7.04 0.20
10V2: dG(mean) dG(rmsd) # it should be always on the first line of output.csv!!
lig2: -5.79 0.45

Comment: ++ I have no idea why: I just added a small suffix "data_" to prefix and it fixed this problem: print "data_" prefix, "dG(rescored)", "dG(rmsd)" > out

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Can you provide a set of filenames so I can reproduce the problem? Actually I'm not fully understanding your structure of filenames as I supposed it may have nothing to do with the computation of rmsd values. If you can fix the problem for yourself, everything is okay.

Comment: Right, thank you! I am going just to test it on many CSV and then accept your answer ..

Comment: awk's semantics for `>` and `>>` aren't the same as shell. `>> out` should just be `> out` (though it'll work OK as-is). Likewise it won't break anything but you don't need `close(out)` as awk will do that for you. You'll get a divide by zero error on all empty input files due to not testing `n` before using it as a divisor in the END section (you do test it in the FNR==1 equivalent code). You should put the common code from FNR==1 and END into a function so it's only defined once but called twice.

Comment: sorry for one more question: could you add also in the awk part a possibility to save into the output additionally a (third) column with a value of the lowest dG (usually located on the first line (with ID1, see my first topic with the demonstration of the input format) of $3 in all CSVs from which we have calculated the mean and rmsd for the same column)? Many thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Hello, I've updated my answer with the requested version. Cheers.

Comment: many many thanks! it works perfect! Cheers

Comment: Thank you for the reply. My pleasure.

Comment: Hello! Just to make some specifications ( while everything is working very well!), I suppose that in the code min = 0 should correspond to the highest  value of $3, since we are dealing indeed only with the negative values arranged from most negative to closest to zero (but in fact dG=0 does not present in the data as well). One question : would this code be useful to print in the same manner the values from $3 (dG) that have maximum values in $2 (column pop ) in initial csv (used for calculations of mean etc) ? So the aim is to print the value from one column based on its value in another

Comment: I suppose so. You'll need to introduce another array which associates $2 value with $3 value, find the maximum $2 with the similar manner as today, then map to the associated $3 to print. Good luck!